# Existence of a measure defined on balls

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Given a metric space $X$, let $B_r(x):=\{y\in X\mid d(x,y)\leq r\}$ be the closed balls. Fix a real number $p>0$. My question now is: Is there a Borel-measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that
\begin{align*}
\mu(B_r(x))=\big(\operatorname{diam} B_r(x)\big)^p,\qquad r>0,x\in X?
\end{align*}
I was thinking about the $p$-dimensional Hausdorff measure, but that has the property that if $\mathcal H^s(A)<\infty$ for some set $A$, then $\mathcal H^t(A)=0$ for $t>s$, and this would contradict the above property, right?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general, there will be no such measure. To see this, consider $\Bbb{Z}$ with the metric $d(x,y)=1$ for $x\neq y$. Then your assumption implies $\mu (\{x\})=0$ for all $x$, but $\mu(\Bbb{Z})>0$, contradicting $\sigma$ additivity.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about that, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. Think of some *infinite*-dimensional Hilbert space. Choose linearly independent unit vectors $(e_n) _{n \in \mathbb N}$. Inside the ball of center $0$ and radius $1$ (which would have measure $2^p$) you can place an infinity of smaller, identical open balls: each one with center at $\frac 1 2 e_n$ and radius $1 \over 4$. These balls would all be disjoint and have measure $({1 \over 2}) ^p$ (your measure, as it is defined, is translation-invariant). So the union of these balls would have infinite measure, but being a subset of the larger ball of radius $1$ would have measure $\leq 2^p$, which is a contradiction. (This is in fact a [classic result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure): there is no non-trivial locally-finite translation-invariant measure on infinite-dimensional vector spaces.)

As you see, your space should have some concept of dimension, and it should be of finite such dimension. In a purely topological context there are [several such notions of dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theory), but once you have this it makes more sense to use the Hasudorff measures.

Comment: This makes sense to me and fits my underlying context perfectly. Thank you.