# Existence of a measure where diameter of balls can be estimated by their measure

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

In my [last post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306485/existence-of-a-measure-defined-on-balls) I asked the following question:

> Given a metric space $X$, let $B_r(x):=\{y\in X\mid d(x,y)\leq r\}$ be the closed balls. Fix a real number $p>0$. My question now is: Is there a Borel-measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that
>   \begin{align*}
> \big(\operatorname{diam} B_r(x)\big)^p=\mu(B_r(x)),\qquad r>0,x\in X?
> \end{align*}

The question had been answered with "No (in general)", and a counterexample can easily be found. Since I do only need inequality instead of equality in the above statement, my new question reads as follows:

> Under the above circumstances, is there a Borel-measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that
>   \begin{align*}
> \big(\operatorname{diam} B_r(x)\big)^p\leq\mu(B_r(x)),\qquad r>0,x\in X?
> \end{align*}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can let $\mu(E)=\infty$ for every nonempty set $E$.

But if you want $\mu(B_r(x))$ to be finite, then no. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the metric $d(x,y)=\min(|x-y|,1)$. Then 
$B_1(0)$ contains $B_{1/3}(n)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and all these balls are disjoint, so $\mu(B_1(0))=\infty$.

---

The property you stated is related to what is known as "lower Ahlfors regularity" in the literature; specifically, $X$ is lower Ahlfors regular with exponent $p$ if there is $c>0$ such that $\mathcal H^p(B_r(x))\ge Cr^p$ for all $x$ and $r$.

Comment: Nice, thank you!